# Truncate and interpolate variable in Vue JS

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-5.6

I'm new to Vue and utilising a World Cup API to build a simple Laravel app. I have the following code:

```
<img src="http://www.countryflags.io/@{{ match.home_team.code | truncate(2) }}/flat/64.png">
```

Which should ideally output the following:

```
<img src="http://www.countryflags.io/FR/flat/64.png">
```

But instead I get an error because it's not parsing the `@{{ }}` block properly inside Laravel/Vue.

This is the truncate filter I'm trying to use incase that's important - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-truncate-filter

`match.home_team.code` should return `FRA` for `France` for example, but I only need `FR`

What is the best way for me to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and do this:

```
<img :src="`http://www.countryflags.io/${match.home_team.code.substring(0, 2)}/flat/64.png`">
```

Might also work with a filter, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Kinda works, but still get a bit of an error with the attempted output. `http://www.countryflags.io/$%7Bmatch.home_team.code.substring(0,2)%7D/flat/64.png 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Did you add `:` to the `:src`?

Comment: YEah copied it exactly as above